# OpenGL-es moving camera through textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a little labyrinth game. It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNVjD.png

However i can not figure how to not allow the camera to move through the boxes

here is the code:

```
public class EulerCameraTest extends GLGame {

//@Override
public Screen getStartScreen() {
    return new EulerCameraScreen(this);
}

class EulerCameraScreen extends GLScreen {      
    Texture crateTexture;       
    Vertices3 cube;
    PointLight light;
    AmbientLight aLight;
    EulerCamera camera;
    Texture buttonTexture;
    SpriteBatcher batcher;
    Camera2D guiCamera;
    TextureRegion buttonRegion;
    Vector2 touchPos;
    float lastX = -1;
    float lastY = -1;

    public EulerCameraScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);    

        crateTexture = new Texture(glGame, "crate.png", true);
        cube = createCube();
        light = new PointLight();
        light.setPosition(3, 3, -3);
        aLight = new AmbientLight();
        aLight.setColor(128, 128, 128, 255);
        camera = new EulerCamera(67, glGraphics.getWidth() / (float)glGraphics.getHeight(), 0.1f, 100);
        camera.getPosition().set(0, 0, 3);

        buttonTexture = new Texture(glGame, "button.png");
        batcher = new SpriteBatcher(glGraphics, 1);
        guiCamera = new Camera2D(glGraphics, 480, 320);
        buttonRegion = new TextureRegion(buttonTexture, 0, 0, 64, 64);
        touchPos = new Vector2();
    }

     private Vertices3 createCube() {
            float[] vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                                  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                 -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,

                                  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                                  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,

                                  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1,
                                 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1,
                                 -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,

                                 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0,
                                 -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0,
                                 -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0,
                                 -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,

                                 -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                                  0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                                 -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,

                                 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0,
                                  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0,
                                  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0,
                                 -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0 };
            short[] indices = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,
                                4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4,
                                8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 8,
                                12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
                                16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
                                20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20,
                                24, 25, 26, 26, 27, 24 };
            Vertices3 cube = new Vertices3(glGraphics, vertices.length / 8, indices.length, false, true, true);
            cube.setVertices(vertices, 0, vertices.length);
            cube.setIndices(indices, 0, indices.length);
            return cube;
        }

    //@Override
    public void resume() {  
        crateTexture.reload();
    }

    //@Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        game.getInput().getTouchEvents();
        float x = game.getInput().getTouchX(0);
        float y = game.getInput().getTouchY(0);
        guiCamera.touchToWorld(touchPos.set(x, y));


        if(game.getInput().isTouchDown(0)) {
            if(touchPos.x < 64 && touchPos.y < 64) {
                Vector3 direction = camera.getDirection();
                direction.y = 0;
                camera.getPosition().add(direction.mul(deltaTime));
            } else {    
                if(lastX == -1) {
                    lastX = x;
                    lastY = y;

                } else {                            
                    camera.rotate((x - lastX) / 10, (y - lastY) / 10);                  
                    lastX = x;
                    lastY = y;
                }
            }
        } else { 
            lastX = -1;
            lastY = -1;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void present(float deltaTime) {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();           
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, glGraphics.getWidth(), glGraphics.getHeight());

        camera.setMatrices(gl);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

        crateTexture.bind();
        cube.bind();        
        light.enable(gl, GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
        aLight.enable(gl);

        int[] matrix = new int[]
                {0,0,0,1,0,
                 0,1,1,1,0,
                 0,1,0,0,0
        };
        int step = 0;
        for(int z = 0; z >= -4/2; z-=2/2)
        {
            for(int x = -4/2; x <=4/2; x+=2/2 )
            {
                if(matrix[step++] == 1)
                    continue;
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                gl.glTranslatef(x, 0, z);
                cube.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * 2 * 3);
                gl.glPopMatrix();
            }
        }

        cube.unbind();

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);           

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        guiCamera.setViewportAndMatrices();
        batcher.beginBatch(buttonTexture);
        batcher.drawSprite(32, 32, 64, 64, buttonRegion);
        batcher.endBatch();

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}   
}
```

I believe that the present() method is where i should be looking in. does anyone have an idea how to make the camera not be able to walk thru the boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `update(float deltaTime)` is where you should be looking. If the camera should not go through the boxes then you should not move it when hitting the box. You need to create a good system to control your movement around the scene and possibly convert some values to the scene coordinate system. To be more general you should separate the physics engine from the graphics engine.

Consider you have an object that represents your scene and has data such as:

```
int width; // The width of the scene
int height; // The height of the scene
bool boxes[width][height]; // The grid of boxes. If the segment is true then a box should be drawn
float playerPositionX;
float playerPositionY;
```

Now your draw method would look something like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < scene.width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < scene.height; y++)
            {
                if(!scene.boxes[y][x])
                    continue;
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                gl.glTranslatef(x*sceneScale, 0, y*sceneScale); // Scene scale is just some constant to make things as large as you want (a box size most likely in your case).
                cube.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * 2 * 3);
                gl.glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
```

But then on your `update` method you would rather simply call something like:

```
scene.movePlayer(x, y);
```

So the scene has a method

```
public void movePlayer(float x, float y) {
    // first get the current position indices:
    int previousX = (int)playerPositionX;
    int previousY = (int)playerPositionY;

    // And the target position:
    int targetX = (int)(playerPositionX+x);
    int targetY = (int)(playerPositionY+y);

    // Now check if you have collisions
    if(targetX < 0 || targetX >= width || boxes[targetX][previousY]) { // The previousY is NOT a bug
        // We hit the wall in X direction so do not move it
        x = .0f;
    }
    if(targetY < 0 || targetY >= height || boxes[previousX][targetY]) { // The previousX is NOT a bug
        // We hit the wall in Y direction so do not move it
        y = .0f;
    }

    playerPositionX += x;
    playerPositionY += y;
}
```

Now all you need to do in the `update` is to set the camera position depending on the scene player position (again apply whatever factors you need such as scene scale).